# Hazelcast, How can I implement a customized MapService by reuse hazelcast internal?

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

The builtin map is memory only, although there is MapStore, writThrough, readThrough etc, but these can not satisfied the requirement. I know I can write a MapService from scratch, but it's too much work to do. Hazelcast's internal MapService is flexible.

So is there any guide to implement a customized map service by reuse hazelcast's internal implementation ? or just point out a way to do this.

PS: I use the hz 3.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is exactly the part you want to get fixed? Because you can override certain parts of the Map internals by overriding the NodeExtension. For more information see DefaultNodeExtension.

It looks a bit (too) complicated, but we use this internally to offer some of our enterprise features for the map like offheap.

We do not have a guide for this since it is meant to be used internally. Also there are no backwards compatibility guarantees on the NodeExtension API since it is internal API.

Comment: So, there is no way except do all the thing by myself, I can reference IMap implement, but it's too complicated, thanks.